# Check whether input values are equal

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I want to use this code for a barcode scanner as follows:

The scanned barcode is entered in the `insert_code` input and then I want to display *"code is ok"*, when the value in `search_code` = `insert_code`.

My code, after validation, clears the input `search_code` and it is annoying to have to reintroduce the same code in `search_code` every time again.

What can I do to keep the value in `search_code` after each validation?

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Cod I:<input type="text" name="search_code" value=""/><br/><br/>
    Cod II:<input type="" name="insert_code" value=""/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="validation" />
</form>

<?php
$search_code = $_POST ["search_code"];
$insert_code = $_POST ["insert_code"];

if ($search_code == $insert_code){
    echo "code is ok";
} else {
    echo "code is not ok";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to still see the `search_code` value from user's input on the page after form submission?

Comment: You don't really need PHP for this. All this can be done in the browser. Is there any other reason you want PHP to be the one who checks that two values are equal?

Comment: @Erica Yes, I want to see the value of 'search_code'

Comment: @trincot Yes, I want PHP because to checks those values is equal.

Comment: But that is my point. Why submit these values to a server, if the client can just compare the values  themselves? It is such a waste of traffic. The server brings no added value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without PHP, which will give a better user-experience. Here is a live example, just run to see it work:

```js
// identify form elements:
var search_code = document.getElementById('search_code');
var insert_code = document.getElementById('insert_code');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var button = document.getElementById('button');

// respond to button click
button.onclick = function validate() {
    // show verification result:
    result.textContent = search_code.value == insert_code.value
        ? 'code is ok'
        : 'code is not ok';
    // clear input when wrong:
    if (search_code.value !== insert_code.value) {
        insert_code.value = '';
    }
    return false;
};

insert_code.oninput = function () {
    result.textContent = ''; // clear result;
};
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    Cod I:<input type="text" name="search_code" id="search_code" value=""/><br/><br/>
    Cod II:<input type="" name="insert_code" id="insert_code" value=""/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" id="button" name="button" value="validation" />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

The test is done in Javascript, which responds to the button click and cancels the form's submission to the server (`return false`).

As a bonus the "ok/not ok" message is cleared as soon as you type a new value in the second input box.

#### How to use this code

Here is how the code should look in your document:

```html
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Cod I:<input type="text" name="search_code" id="search_code" value=""/><br/><br/>
        Cod II:<input type="" name="insert_code" id="insert_code" value=""/><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="button" name="button" value="validation" />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <script>
    // identify form elements:
    var search_code = document.getElementById('search_code');
    var insert_code = document.getElementById('insert_code');
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    var button = document.getElementById('button');

    // respond to button click
    button.onclick = function validate() {
        // show verification result:
        result.textContent = search_code.value == insert_code.value
            ? 'code is ok'
            : 'code is not ok';
        // clear input when wrong:
        if (search_code.value !== insert_code.value) {
            insert_code.value = '';
        }
        return false;
    };

    insert_code.oninput = function () {
        result.textContent = ''; // clear result;
    };
    </script>
</body>
```

Note that the content part has some differences to yours: every input has an **id** attribute, and there is an extra **div**.

Comment: I insered your code in <HTML> and not function, why?

Comment: I added a paragraph to my answer repeating the code as it should look in your document. The way StackOverflow shows a *snippet* can be misleading as the script tags are not displayed and the order is also wrong: the Javascript script tag should appear after the content (form).

Comment: Function this code. If the code is true, can stay in input `insert_code`?

Comment: Works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep `search_code` input filled with the last submitted value, just echo the value of this post into the input if it was set:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Cod I:<input type="text" name="search_code" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['search_code'])?$_POST['search_code']:'' ?>"/><br/><br/>
    Cod II:<input type="" name="insert_code" value=""/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="validation" />
</form>
```

Also, to avoid warnings about undefined index, add this condition to your PHP code (check if those posts are set):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST ["search_code"]) && isset($_POST ["insert_code"])){
    $search_code = $_POST ["search_code"];
    $insert_code = $_POST ["insert_code"];

    if ($search_code == $insert_code){
        echo "code is ok";
    }else {
        echo "code is not ok";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If code from `insert_code` is equal with `search_code` we can do to stay in input `insert_code`?